# python error:unable to find vcvarsall.bat while installing sklearn windows 8 (installed python2.7 32bit installer and packages(numpy,scipy,etc))

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

i recently installed python 2.7 and installed numpy,scipy and matplotlib via pip (setting env ) for sklearn kit for machine learning , i also installed vcpython.exe for c++ and it

but it show the following error about vcvarsall.bat (tried all of your post didn't worked for me )
pls it is sem project !!
last few lines of the output while typing (c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn>python setup.py install in cmd)

No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_clib
building 'libsvm-skl' library
compiling C sources
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Comment: You should download the Anaconda distribution instead. It resolves this issue for you and provides you with all the libraries you mentioned.